# How to use the REST API to Update Provider Config?

Tags: cluedin

While trying to use the CluedIn REST API command to update provider configuration details the response is the html code for the CluedIn webpage (error) without any details as to why.  When checking the values which should be updated, they are not.

What is the correct process to update provider configuration variables via the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with CluedIn 3.2.4, you can update the integration configuration from the "Authentication" tab:
[image]

If you are on earlier 3.x versions, you have to do two steps: get the provider configuration, and update the provider configuration.

Before you start, please get an authentication token:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 
  'https://orgname.domain/auth/connect/token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data-urlencode 'username=admin@domain' \
  --data-urlencode 'password=yourstrongpassword' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_id=int' \
  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

Example response:

```json
{
    "access_token": "...",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": "...",
    "scope": "offline_access openid profile ServerApiForUI SpecificBlobApi"
}
```

Now, get the provider configuration.
First, you need the configuration ID. That's the last part of the URL when you open the configured integration in the browser. I.e. `https://orgname.domain/admin/configuration/integration-guid/youneed-this-guid`.

Now run:

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'https://orgname.domain/api/api/configuration/providers?id=your-integration-configuration-guid' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer your-auth-token'
```

Expected response:

```json
{
    "ProviderId": "...",
    "Name": "...",
    "Guide": null,
    "PlanLevel": 1,
    "Configuration": {
        "Authorization": "...",
        "firstTime": false,
        "LastCrawlFinishTime": "2021-10-27T08:38:51.9620662+00:00",
        "lastCursor": {}
    },
    "Active": true,
    "OrganizationId": "...",
    "Type": "Cloud",
    "helperConfiguration": {
        "ClientId": "...",
        "ClientSecret": "..."
    },
    "CodeName": "...",
    "UserId": "...",
    "SourceQuality": 5,
    "Source": "",
    "AutoSync": false,
    "AuthType": null,
    "Id": "...",
    "UserName": "admin@domain",
    "AuthTypes": null,
    "AccountId": "",
    "AccountDisplay": "Integration Name",
    "EntityId": "...",
    "SupportsConfiguration": true,
    "SupportsWebhooks": false,
    "SupportsAutomaticWebhookCreation": true,
    "FailingAuthentication": false,
    "Stats": {
        "Name": "Provider Stats",
        "ProviderStatus": {
            "Crawling": {
                "$type": "CluedIn.Server.WebApi.Models.Providers.ProviderStatusCrawlInfo, CluedIn.Server.WebApi",
                "TaskCount": 0,
                "TasksCompletedCount": 0,
                "TasksCompletedPerMinute": 0.0,
                "TasksFailedCount": 0,
                "TasksQueuedCount": 0,
                "ExpectedTasksCount": 0
            },
            "Processing": null,
            "State": "Crawling",
            "Summary": null
        },
        "ProviderId": "...",
        "ConfigurationId": "...",
        "OrganizationId": "..."
    },
    "Status": {
        "NextExecution": "2021-10-27T12:38:00Z"
    },
    "WebhookManagementEndpoints": null,
    "Webhooks": null,
    "DataStatistics": {
        "EntityTypeStatistics": []
    },
    "ExpectedData": 0,
    "ExpectedStatistics": null,
    "ExpectedTaskCount": 0,
    "ExpectedTime": "00:00:00",
    "CreatedDate": "2021-07-28T08:37:50.7865925+00:00"
}
```

In this response, change the `helperConfiguration` and `Put` it back in a response body:

```sh
curl --location --request PUT 'https://orgname.domain/api/api/v2/organization/Providers?accountId=&providerId=your-configuration-guid' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer your-access-token' \
  --data-raw 'your-updated-json'
```

Expected response:

```json
{
    "AccountDisplay": "...",
    "AutoSync": false,
    "Source": "",
    "SourceQuality": 5,
    "Id": "...",
    "appUrl": "",
    "SupportsWebHooks": false,
    "SupportsAutomaticWebhookCreation": true,
    "SupportsConfiguration": true,
    "helperConfiguration": {
        "ClientId": "...",
        "ClientSecret": "...",
        "Authorization": "...",
        "firstTime": false,
        "LastCrawlFinishTime": "01/01/0001 00:00:00 +00:00",
        "lastCursor": ""
    },
    "configurationDictionary": {
        "ClientId": "...",
        "ClientSecret": "...",
        "Authorization": "...",
        "firstTime": false,
        "LastCrawlFinishTime": "01/01/0001 00:00:00 +00:00",
        "lastCursor": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Roman,  Can you please share what the Response Body should look like?  We tried various formats based off the provider GET response and when we try to POST instead of getting confirmation, we receive the source code for the CluedIn homepage and the value in the helperConfiguration is not changed.

Comment: Hi John, I have updated my answer and added the expected response. Please, keep in mind that the request method must be `PUT`, not `POST`.